# Variables globales en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito guardar en una variable global, `dataToSend`, el resultado de un child_process que ejecuta un script en python. Pero cuando accedo a esta función fuera de de las funciones en resultado es undefined.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

var json = {
  etapa: "INICIACION",
  animal: {
    ganancia: { "unit-weight": { unit: "g", amount: 400 } },
    peso: { "unit-weight": { unit: "kg", amount: 50 } }
  },
  ingredientes: [
    {
      ingredientes: "Grano de Cebada",
      "unit-currency": { amount: 7, unit: "MXN" }
    },
    {
      ingredientes: "Heno de Alfalfa",
      "unit-currency": { unit: "MXN", amount: 3 }
    },
    {
      ingredientes: "Pasta de Soya",
      "unit-currency": { unit: "ARS", amount: 14 }
    }
  ]
};
var dataToSend;
var message;
toPython = JSON.stringify(json);
// spawn new child process to call the python script
const python = spawn("python", ["Feeder.py", toPython]);
// collect data from script
python.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
  dataToSend = data.toString("latin1");
});
// in close event we are sure that stream from child process is closed
python.on("close", code => {
  console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
  console.log(dataToSend); // send data to browser
});
```

La información guardad en dataToSend es:

```
Grano de Cebada:  85.0
Heno de Alfalfa:  2.0
Pasta de Soya:  13.0
```

Pero al acceder a esa misma variable de manera global, el resultado `undefined`

Comment: El resultado es un string, verdad? Haz intentado dar un string vacío (' ') como valor inicial a dataToSend?

Comment: Las variable con alcance global se definen con `var`, tal vez tienes el problema en otro lado

Comment: Cuando haces el close, en la ultima linea de tu código. el console.log que tienes muestra la info bien o allí es el undefined ya??